# QSqlTableModel::insertRecord() fails with QSqlDatabase with a non-default connection name

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, qt

Using `Qt 4.8.6` and `clang++ x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0` on my late-2014 MacBook Pro I find that `QsqlTableModel::insertRecord()` fails to write the target `MYSQL` database: `myDB` while constructing the `QSqlDatbase`: `myDB` using a non-default connection such as:

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL","Connection1");
```

and `insertRecord(-1,myRecord)` evaluates to `false`.

Instead, if I use the usual default connection:

```
db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
```

the database is appended successfully as:

```
mysql> select * from myTable;
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |
|    5 |    6 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The usual recommendation to accommodate multiple connection names is to construct `QSqlQuery` with `QSqlDatabase` as:

```
QSqlQuery query(db)
```

that evidently doesn't seem to help in this case. Can you point out what's missing?

The small amount of runnable code that exemplifies the above is below:

**testdb.h**

```
#ifndef TESTDB_H
#define TESTDB_H

#include <QtSql>
#include <QtCore>


class TestDB
{
public:
    TestDB();
    ~TestDB();
    void dbInit();
    void appendDB(const int &col1, const int &col2);
private:
    QSqlDatabase db;
    QSqlTableModel *model;
};

#endif // TESTDB_H
```

**testdb.cpp**

```
#include "testdb.h"

TestDB::TestDB()
{
    dbInit();
}

TestDB::~TestDB()
{

}

void TestDB::dbInit()
{
    // database connection
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL","Connection1");
    db.setDatabaseName("myDB"); 
    db.setUserName("root");
    db.setPassword("");
    db.setHostName("localhost");
    db.setConnectOptions();
    if (!db.open())
    {
        qDebug() << "Database error occurred in class: stockinfo" << db.lastError().text();
    }
    QSqlQuery query(db);

    // create database named transactions
    query.exec("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS myDB;");
    query.exec("USE myDB;");
    query.exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable("
                   "col1 INT,"
                   "col2 INT"
                   ");");
    model = new QSqlTableModel;
    model->setTable("myTable");
    model->select();
}

void TestDB::appendDB(const int &col1, const int &col2)
{
    QSqlRecord myRecord;
    myRecord.append(QSqlField("col1", QVariant::Int));
    myRecord.append(QSqlField("col2", QVariant::Int));

    myRecord.setValue("col1",col1);
    myRecord.setValue("col2",col2);

    model->insertRecord(-1,myRecord);
    qDebug() << "model->insertRecord(-1,myRecord) = " << model->insertRecord(-1,myRecord);
    qDebug() << "Last Database error: " << db.lastError().text();
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <testdb.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    TestDB myTestDB;
    myTestDB.appendDB(1,2);
    myTestDB.appendDB(5,6);
    return a.exec();
}
```

**dbTest.pro**

```
QT       += core sql

QT       -= gui

TARGET = dbTest
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp \
    testdb.cpp

HEADERS += \
    testdb.h
```

Comment: I googled my way to (http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/26441-SOLVED-addDatabase-with-connectionName-problem?s=e73506fea8e90c947c480e55e5e36b66&p=125931#post125931), that was 1 search of "QSqlDatabase::addDatabase" + 1 click (on the hit saying "SOLVED:") + 1 scroll. Hopefully it helps. In short, when you use a connection name for opening the database, you have to specify that connection name in the query.

Comment: Thanks, but as I had already pointed out I do pass the constructor for `QSqlQuery` with `QSqlDatabase`. Nevertheless, the approach suggested in your link produces the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, I only see the name "Connection1" once in the posted code. Maybe I'm equally blind on one eye as on the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating `QSqlTableModel` (testdb.cpp:35) you do not specify any database connection, therefore your model wraps default connection. This is probably not what you wanted, not tested. See [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsqltablemodel.html#QSqlTableModel)